# Node.js + Apache + MySQL + phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, node.js, apache, phpmyadmin

I want to host my Node.js SPA website on domain

> www.xxx.com
>    without port number on  Ubuntu Server and i need to use MySQL + phpMyAdmin.

But Im quite new in those technology.
So I need install Lamp and redirect port 80 to node.js?
But still need to have access to

> www.xxx.com/phpmyadmin

...

Is there any conflict?

Do you have some recommendation how to connect it well? Or easy step by step...

Comment: Read this article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

Set Up Nginx

Comment: I just set apache port to 8080 and Node 80 :) and my problem is solved, im using port 8080 for using phpMyAdmin :)